# jest testing pass variable to another test

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to assign a variable from one test to be accessed within another test.  For example:

```
let user;

test('create new user', async () => {
  const response = await createUser()
  user = response
})

test('delete user', async () => {
  const response = await deleteUser(user.id)
})
```

I understand that jest has a `--runInBand` option, however this still has user as `undefined` in "delete user".  Any ideas how to accomplish this with jest? Thank you

Comment: I replicated the same code in sandbox[https://codesandbox.io/s/p77xpx0wn7] (as jest not available in Stackoverflow snippets). The code works perfectly fine. Might need more details on how it has been implemented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each test runs independently, and for good reason. Tests should be confirming isolated conditions, methods, and logic. All `--runInBand` does is run the tests in serially, but they still won't necessarily be able to share data objects the way you seem to be expecting.

Also, assuming these methods defer to a backend service of some kind, you're not going to easily be able to fully test the behavior of that system. It sounds like you want an *end-to-end* or *integration* testing framework, as opposed to a *unit* testing framework like Jest.

Keeping with Jest, you're likely going to need to mock whatever backend service is being called in `createUser` and `deleteUser`. Jest [mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) can help replace external functions with new ones that create the types of conditions you want to test.

Alternatively or in addition, you might be able to stub your `user` object using [beforeAll](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeallfn-timeout) or [beforeEach](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeeachfn-timeout), creating sample data that allows you to test how `deleteUser` behaves when it's passed a particular object (likely bypassing whatever backend persistence with an aforementioned mock).

Comment: Thanks @benjarwar - think I'll just head back to mocha for this.

Comment: @dzm sure thing. But I think you'll run into similar problems with mocha, unless you're running these in a test environment, including back-end services, that's dedicated to running your tests. Like, you definitely wouldn't want to run this against production servers/databases.

Comment: We can maybe advise further if you post the `deleteUser` and `createUser` code.

Comment: Yeah, it's a test env for an internal api, i've done similar tests in mocha fine, but recently started using jest.

Comment: I think Jest is fine for E2E tests as well. You just write one long test or divide it using functions. This way its logic will run serially, and you can use variables from a previous step.

Comment: The problem, as you stated in your (great) answer, is with the tests the asker wrote. Each test should have the following steps: setup (optional), the actual test, and tear-down (optional). To test the deletion of a user, you need to first create it in the setup of that test, and not in a different test altogether. BTW, in these specific tests - it will make a lot of sense to unite them into a single test (create, check that was created, delete, check that was deleted).

Answer (score 1):

You can create the variables in the `describe` and then assign them in the `beforeAll()` or `beforeEach()`. If your tests haven't already deleted it, you could/should delete the values in the `afterEach()` or `afterAll()`.

```js
describe('My Test', () => {
  let user: User;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    user = await createUser();
  });

  test('delete user', async () => {
    const response = await deleteUser(user.id);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is a nonsense "tip". This code looks exactly like the OP code but shows what to do. I will add some text but the answer is clear. It is clear you are just trying to gain reputation.